# Getting permissions on Ubuntu to create Eclipse project

Tags: ubuntu, security, permissions, eclipse

I am trying to set up a new project in Eclipse, but it gives me an error saying that the directory where I am trying to set up the project is read-only.

Here is the error:
Parent of resource: /path/to/project/.project is marked as read-only. (Permission denied)

I do know the password for the machine to get root permissions.  How can I use it to give Eclipse complete editing permissions so that this error does not happen?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're logging in as a non-root user `myuser`, simply run:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /path/to/project
```

which will make you the owner of that directory (and subdirectories).

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! It solved the problem I was trying to get rid from 15 days